# Django ajax-- Empty request.FILE when I am sending a form with Ajax, Django

Tags: python, ajax, django, forms

I am using Django 1.5.2, jQuery v1.9.0 and POSTGRESQL 9.1.

I am sending a form using ajax but requst.FILE is empty, the imgen is not sending.

here are my files.

Models.py

```
class Evento(models.Model):
    nombre            = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre 

class Imagen(models.Model):    
    def url(self,filename):
        ruta = "MultimediaData/Evento/%s/%s"%(self.evento.id,str(filename))
        return ruta
    evento = models.ForeignKey(Evento)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=url)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.photo)
```

URSL.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('CasadeAna.apps.home.views',        
        url(r'^addevento/$','addevent_view',name='event_add'), 
        url(r'^editevento/(?P<idevento>.*)/$','editevent_view',name='event_edit'), 
)
```

VIEW.py

```
def editevent_view(request,idevento):

        if request.method == 'GET' and request.is_ajax():
            formulario = FormImagen()
            ctx = {'form':formulario}
            return render_to_response('home/event/imagenform.html',ctx,context_instance=RequestContext(request))

        elif request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
            print 'dasd'
            print request.POST
            print request.FILES 
            print 'dasd'
            formulario =  FormImagen(request.POST,request.FILES)

            if formulario.is_valid():
                formulario.save()
                return HttpResponse('very good')         
            else:
                ctx = {'form':formulario}
                return render_to_response('home/event/imagenform.html',ctx,context_instance=RequestContext(request))

        elif request.method == 'GET':
            evento = Evento.objects.get(id=idevento)
            ctx = {'evento':evento}
            imagen = Imagen.objects.filter(evento=evento)
            return render_to_response('home/event/editEvent.html',ctx,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

HTML

FORM

imagenform.html

```
<form id="formulario" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <button type="submit"class="btn btn-primary" onClick="enviar(this);">Guardar</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Limpiar</button>
</form>
```

editEvent.html

```
 {% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block menu %}
{% endblock %}
{% block  content %}
<div style="height:100%;"  align="left" >
    <h1 class="muted"> Editar Imagenes </h1>
  <h2>{{evento.nombre}}</h2>
    <div id="imagenes">
        <div id="menu" >
            <button class="btn" onClick="subirImagen(this);">Agregar Imagen <i class="icon-plus"></i></button>
        <div>           
        <div id="contenedor">
            <ul class="thumbnails">
            {% if  imagen %}
                {% for i in imagen %}
                     <li class="span4">
                        <img data-src="{{i.photo}}" alt="">
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
{% endblock %}
{% block js %}
 <script type="text/javascript">
    //pedir formulario para subir una imagen 
    function subirImagen(e)
    {
        $.ajax({
              url: '/editevento/14/',
              type: 'GET',
              dataType: 'html',
              success: function(datos){
                   $('#contenedor').empty();
                   $('#contenedor').append(datos);
                }
            });
    }
  function enviar(e)
  {
        $('#formulario').submit(function(evento){
            evento.preventDefault();
            var datos_formulario = $(this).serialize();        
            alert('event444os');
            $.ajax({
                url: '/editevento/14/',
                data: datos_formulario,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                processData:false,
                cache:false,
                success: function(datos){
                    $('#contenedor').empty();
                    $('#contenedor').append(datos);
                }
            });
        });
    }
 </script>
{% endblock %}
```

to submit a form request.post value and file is
request.POST

request.FILES

please, help!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot post files like this. have a look at this question: [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery) or this question: [jQuery ajax post file field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718888/jquery-ajax-post-file-field)

Comment: Could you be more specific with your explanation? Links are helpful, but even more helpful would be an actual explanation about why you cannot post files like "this", whatever "this" is.